# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in google map

Tags: javascript

I was working with the Google Map API and the code showed below throws an error when executing. It appears that the Map suddenly disappears:

```
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 1);
    map.setUIToDefault();
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
  }
}

function showAddress(address) {   
  // var address = {zipcode} or {city and state};
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.getLatLng(
      address,
      function(point) {
        if (!point) {
          alert(address + " not found");
        } else {
          map.setCenter(point, 15);
          var marker = new GMarker(point, {draggable: true});
          map.addOverlay(marker);
          GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(marker.getLatLng().toUrlValue(6));
          });
          GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(marker.getLatLng().toUrlValue(6));
          });
          GEvent.trigger(marker, "click");
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my API key if you want to run some tests (coming from a free account):

```
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyA6zCY_71F8OzaWmBZcWvLH9xbarUGrvJs'></script>
```

I think the error occurred within the function's initialization, I am not sure and I could use some help. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: please help. what was the error

Comment: In which line was the error thrown?

Comment: @maowtm seems like the error is thrown from api js, not from posted js

Comment: yes. its from common.js in api. different errors : Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError